# Change font lock interactive ESS buffer

Tags: r, emacs, ess, font-lock

I use ESS to run R and sometimes evaluate long blocks of code interactively. I'd like errors to stick out in the interactive process.

Currently, `Error:` messages generated by R appear in a greenish-blue font lock color. I'd like something more dramatic, maybe a red background and white text. Can anyone tell me how to edit my `.emacs` file to achieve this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. It was solved in ESS v13.09. Thanks.

edit: The bug was that "Error:" type keywords were re-highlighted by compilation mode and that the "normal" font-lock-warning-face was not getting through.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. What is the "bug"?

Comment: @VitoshKa It would be worth mentioning, when someone looks back at this in the future, either what was the last released version with the bug or the first released version where this bug was fixed.